How to group sum Array column by another Array column's elements in Clickhouse
I have a Clickhouse table having multiple Array columns, such as
timestamp  sensor_type                    priority                values
10:00:00   ['a','b','b','a','c','a','c']  [3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1]   [7, 4, 1, 12, 3, 9, 2]
10:01:00   ['c','e','g','e','g']          [2, 4, 1, 2, 4]         [23, 3, 5, 8, 6]
...

The timestamps are unique and monotonically increasing. The sensors that have values recorded are dynamically changing at each timestamp. I'm trying to group and sum up the values array by sensor_type or priority for each timestamp, so the expected aggregated columns are like:
timestamp  sensor_type_sorted  sum_val_by_sensor_type  priority_sorted  sum_val_by_priority
10:00:00   ['a', 'b', 'c']     [28, 5, 5]              [1, 2, 3, 5]     [6, 13, 7, 12]
10:01:00   ['c', 'e', 'g']     [23, 11, 11]            [1, 2, 4]        [5, 31, 9]
...

How to achieve this?

Try this way:
WITH data AS
  (
    SELECT timestamp, sensor_type, priority, values
    FROM VALUES('timestamp DateTime, sensor_type Array(String), priority Array(Int32), values Array(Int32)', 
      ('2024-01-01 10:00:00', ['a','b','b','a','c','a','c'], [3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1], [7, 4, 1, 12, 3, 9, 2]), 
      ('2024-01-01 10:01:00', ['c','e','g','e','g'],         [2, 4, 1, 2, 4],       [23, 3, 5, 8, 6]))
  )
SELECT
    timestamp,
    arrayReduce('sumMap', [sensor_type], [values]) AS sensor_result,
    sensor_result.1 AS sensor_type_sorted,
    sensor_result.2 AS sum_val_by_sensor_type,
    arrayReduce('sumMap', [priority], [values]) AS priority_result,
    priority_result.1 AS priority_sorted,
    priority_result.2 AS sum_val_by_priority    
FROM data

/*
┌───────────timestamp─┬─sensor_result──────────────┬─sensor_type_sorted─┬─sum_val_by_sensor_type─┬─priority_result─────────┬─priority_sorted─┬─sum_val_by_priority─┐
│ 2024-01-01 10:00:00 │ (['a','b','c'],[28,5,5])   │ ['a','b','c']      │ [28,5,5]               │ ([1,2,3,5],[6,13,7,12]) │ [1,2,3,5]       │ [6,13,7,12]         │
│ 2024-01-01 10:01:00 │ (['c','e','g'],[23,11,11]) │ ['c','e','g']      │ [23,11,11]             │ ([1,2,4],[5,31,9])      │ [1,2,4]         │ [5,31,9]            │
└─────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
*/


First pivot values of columns "sensor_type and values" into rows. Then to calculate the sum, 'group by' on 'id, type' and then again convert rows into columns.
Query1:
select id, collect_list(typ) as sensor_type_sorted, collect_list(val) as sum_val_by_sensor_type from (
select id, typ, sum(val) as val from (
select s.id, s_type.typ, s_value.val 
from sensor s
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(s.type) s_type as seqt, typ 
LATERAL VIEW POSEXPLODE(s.value) s_value as seqv, val 
where seqt=seqv) temp1
group by id, typ
order by id, typ) calcultd
group by id;

Do same for columns "priority and values" to create query2. Join query1 and query2 on id.
